# Iron-Session save/destroy not working in Next.js Middleware before NextResponse.redirect

Tags: session, next.js, middleware

If I try and save or destroy the Iron-Session session before a redirect the changes has no effect, but if there is no redirect and 'middleware' exits via 'return res' all is fine

Have a look at [Iron-Session - Middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-session?activeTab=readme#nextjs-middlewares-usage) and imagine there is a 'session.destroy()' just before the 'return NextResponse.redirect'

I reckon it is because the session changes are done on the 'res' object and that is not used in the redirect.
Any ideas on how to make the changes stick when doing a redirect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.